# Fastest data structure for access/modification in Java

Tags: java, performance, data-structures

Hi there Stackoverflowers!

I was coding a project when I wondered which is the fastest data structure that allows me the best performance if I have to access/edit a lot that data?

Let me explain with an example.
I have a class called User and a class Event. A User can have many events. Until now, I have implemented this situation with an ArrayList:

```
public class User{
    ArrayList<Event> events;
    public void process(){
    }
    ...
}
public class Event{
    event data like event time etc.
}
```

Since I have a lot of users(millions), every user can have potentially thousands of events, and, moreover, I have to access every event of a user with process() method, I think that using structures like HashMaps etc. would not be helpful(If am wrong please tell me).
However, it is obvious that with this number of elements, good performance is a need.

So, what do you think the fastest data structure to handle the events is?

Thank you very much,

Marco.

Comment: Depends on how you want to handle events. Does order matter? If so, is it a FIFO or LIFO data structure?

Comment: I'd rather delegate this to a database

Comment: i agree with LeleDumbo, if you have millions of users it just begs for a database...

Comment: @m0skit0 no, the order which I access the data with doesn't matter since I have to access every event

Comment: @MarcoGalassi: Do you need random access to those events? E.g. "Give me the event with UID 0x69696969"? Or do you just treat them as an unsorted pile?

Comment: I wouldn't store the events in a data structure, instead I would process each event as they occur in the current thread or a thread pool. You can't get more light weight than doing nothing at all. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a job better suited for a database, especially if you want persistence and/or your data may not fit in the main memory of your computer.

If, however, you insist on doing this in your own code, you might want to have a look at the [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) class. It allows direct access to its elements with constant (i.e. O(1)) complexity, while also combining an internal linked list to allow fast iteration over all elements.

Of course, whether a `HashMap` structure is helpful depends on what you want to do. If, for example, you want to search events based on some kind of identifier, then a `HashMap` is ideal.

On the other hand, if you only need to access events based on their insertion order, then you cannot do much better than [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), since it supports indexed access to its contents with a constant complexity. If you just need to process them in a queue or stack, Java has several implementations of the [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface that might interest you.

Lastly, if you want to insert your keys randomly and have the underlying structure sort them itself, you might find the [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) class useful.

Comment: I don't think that using a database would solve the performance problem.If I use a database, haven't I an additional performance issue derived from the need to retrieve the data from it?

I mean, if I access the data on my machine instead of a database, it should be really really faster.


Isn't it?

Comment: @MarcoGalassi: 1. You can always run your database on the same host. 2. Are you certain that your data will always fit in the available memory? If you are going to use the disk, better let the DB do it - it will be far better than you at it. 3. What are your persistence and coherence requirements? Do you need transactions? What happens when your program terminates. What happens if it crashes?

Comment: @MarcoGalassi: I forgot the most important argument: You appear to be assuming the existence of a performance problem before actually trying out your application. Premature optimization is the mother of all evils - never optimize anything before your profiler tells you to...

Answer (score 1):

There are two things:

1- in current scenario, if concurrent users are not a concern then you can easily go for arraylist as its faster simpler data structure else if concurrent users are the concern then you can easily go for vector to store your events.

2- you can use queue DS, which will help you in dynamic operations like insertion/deletion which is faster then arraylist and vecotr as it uses iterator.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your data fits into main memory,  your best solution would be java collections and 
plain arrays (depending on needs for random access,  sequentiality, needs to persisting changes  or whatever else)  If your data grows past single system memory your will have better performance with some clusterable no-sql solution (again, choice of the right tool 
depends on what you likt to do with your data)